# Car crash reaction time

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator, timer, physics

In physics class we are doing an investigation thing. Some of the numbers might seem plucked out of thin air but they aren't. The maths is right(I think) I just want some feedback on the code.

```
import datetime
import random
import time
import math


player_1 = input("Player one: ")
speed = int(input("Speed in km/h: "))
speed_ms = ((speed)/3.6)
conditions = input("Wet or dry conditions? (all lowercase)")

if conditions == "wet":
    friction_coefficient = 0.4
else:
    friction_coefficient = 0.6


time.sleep(0.5)
print("Get ready..")
time.sleep(random.randint(1,12))
then = datetime.datetime.now()
t = input("GO!! ")
now = datetime.datetime.now()
diff = then-now
reaction_time = round(abs(diff.total_seconds()), 2)


Rt = (math.sqrt((reaction_time*98)/490))
print('Your final reaction time was: ', (Rt), '!\n')

Rd = (Rt * speed_ms)
print('Your final reaction distance was: ', (Rd), '!\n')

Bd = (((speed_ms)**2) / 19.6 * (friction_coefficient))
print('Your final breaking distance was: ', (Bd), '!\n')

Sd = ((Rd)+(Bd))

############################################################################

print("\n\n---===========FINAL STOPPING DISTANCE===========---")
print('--------------', (Sd), 'meters', '------------')
```

Comment: Spelling - **braking** (from verb "to brake"), not "breaking" (from "to break").  Different things, though easily confused as they sound the same.

Comment: I'm not a mathematician nor a physician but I doubt that I could stop a car going 130km/h in 40 meters, even with an immediate reaction

Comment: @ThomasAyoub: I hope physicians only need to get involved when the braking distance is too large anyway.

Comment: This doesn’t warrant an answer but you *should really* follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide. In particular, your identifiers should follow Python style.

Comment: I think it came from an incorrect interpretation/manipulation of the "drop the ruler" reaction time `t = sqrt(2*d / g)`, with distance in cm, which simplified to `t = sqrt(d/490)`.

Answer (score 36):

- > Some of the numbers might seem plucked out of thin air but they aren't

  Still better have them explained. I can understand `3.6` and even `19.6` (it is \$2g\$, isn't it?), but I have no idea what `98/490` stands for. Declare them as symbolic constants with meaningful names.
- I don't see a need for `abs` in

  ```
      reaction_time = round(abs(diff.total_seconds()), 2)
  ```

  Here `diff` may not be negative. If it is, I'd rather throw an exception, because the result is meaningless anyways.
- You are rounding too early. There is no penalty computing `Rt` with reaction time not being rounded, but rounding leads to loss of precision. Only round when printing results.
- You have too many parenthesis. `Sd = Bd + Rd` is much cleaner than `Sd = ((Rd)+(Bd))`.

Comment: Surely now will always be greater than then, so diff will always be negative? Though would probably make more sense to remove the abs, and set `diff = now - then`

Comment: `now` may not always be greater than `then`. For example the last second of 2016, 2016-12-31T23:59:60 might be less than the penultimate second 2016-12-31T23:59:59.99 because I'm not sure if https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second is implemented properly for UNIX times. You should `assert now > then`

Comment: Using a timer function like time.time() or timeit.default_timer(), instead of datetime, should prevent the issue, I would imagine. It is probably also a more appropriate abstraction for what is being measured, i.e. a length of elapsed time from a stopwatch, rather than a distance between two points on a calendar. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/measure-time-elapsed-in-python

Comment: [Crossover commenting](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/189639/car-crash-reaction-time/189649?noredirect=1#comment362624_189649) from Mattias's post: Why has no one pointed out that `98 / 490` is `/ 5`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 There must be a reason why `1/5` is honored with such encoding. Otherwise division by 5 would still make no sense to me.

Comment: But it is already a magic number. Multiplying by \$10g\$ and dividing by \$50g\$

Comment: @hjpotter92 The formula computes the actual reaction time from the raw reaction time. I don't see how \$g\$ may play any role here. Besides, due to `sqrt`, the magic factor must be measured in seconds.

Comment: @vnp The distinction between "Actual" reaction time vs. "raw" reaction time makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Mordred To me neither. I only state what the code is doing. If you have a better explanation, please do.

Comment: Note: I think now - then can be negative if the clock goes back an hour during that period (could be DST or timezone related). At least, I know that in Java and C#, DateTime.Now can have this bug, not sure if Python has the same bug.

Comment: @Nzall: But it's not a bug. It's 100% accurate. That's what it _needs_ to do.  If you want it to not do that, then you're using the wrong tool, and should probably be looking at `java.time.Clock` instead.

Comment: @csiz correctly notes that `datetime.datetime.now()` is not monotonic. But `assert now > then` is only a patch to sometimes catch the problem. If there's a leap second backward, but my code actually takes three seconds, then `now` will be `then + two_seconds`—the assertion passes, but the answer is wrong. The _only_ correct solution is to use a monotonic clock in the first place.

Comment: @Nzall As Mooing Duck says what else would you expect `DateTime.Now` to return if not the current datetime? The right tool for the job is a clock that is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing. In C# you can use the `Stopwatch` class (particularly nice since it already deals with all the details of measuring time) and in Java the right tool is `System.nanoTime()`. In python it should be `time.monotonic()`.

Comment: @Voo and others I probably shouldn't have called it a bug. I mean it as a bug in the program where diff CAN be negative. Although if Diff in this case IS negative, calling abs on it would only cause the error to be massively increased.

Answer (score 18):

I suggest breaking the code into functions, so you can easily `import` your code into a Python shell and test that your computation is exact (and not just thinking it is).

To expand on other answers, you may:

- retry asking the speed if it is not an integer (detected when the `int` function raises a `ValueError`);
- in the same vein, since you don't really need to check for both `wet` and `dry`, you could ask a simple yes/no question;
- flush the input stream before printing GO (using [`termios`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/termios.html#termios.tcflush) on linux or [`msvcrt`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.kbhit) on windows);
- prefer [`time.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) to `datetime.now()` to compute the time elapsed between two points in the program;
- compute all the results before printing them.

Proposed improvements:

```
import random
import time


def flush_input():
    try:
        import msvcrt
        while msvcrt.kbhit():
            msvcrt.getch()
    except ImportError:
        import sys, termios    #for linux/unix
        termios.tcflush(sys.stdin, termios.TCIOFLUSH)


def ask_speed():
    while True:
        speed = input("Speed in km/h: ")
        try:
            return int(speed)
        except ValueError:
            print("An integer is required!")


def ask_is_wet():
    is_wet = input("Is the road wet? [y/n] ")
    return is_wet.lower() in ('y', 'yes')


def compute_distances(speed_kmh, reaction_time, is_wet):
    speed_ms = speed_kmh / 3.6
    friction_coefficient = 0.4 if is_wet else 0.6

    reaction_time = (reaction_time * 98 / 490)**.5
    reaction_distance = reaction_time * speed_ms
    braking_distance = speed_ms**2 / (19.6 * friction_coefficient)
    total_distance = reaction_distance + braking_distance

    return reaction_time, reaction_distance, braking_distance, total_distance


def get_reaction_time(prompt="GO!! "):
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 12))
    then = time.perf_counter()
    flush_input()
    input(prompt)
    now = time.perf_counter()
    return now - then


def main():
    name = input("Player one: ")
    speed = ask_speed()
    is_wet = ask_is_wet()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Get ready..")
    reaction_time = get_reaction_time()

    reaction, distance, braking, total = compute_distances(speed, reaction_time, is_wet)

    print('Your final reaction time was: ', reaction, '!\n')
    print('Your final reaction distance was: ', distance, '!\n')
    print('Your final braking distance was: ', braking, '!\n')
    print("\n\n---===========FINAL STOPPING DISTANCE===========---")
    print('--------------', total, 'meters', '------------')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why has no one pointed out that `98 / 490` is `/ 5`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 This should be a better addition to vnp's answer

Answer (score 13):

- It crashes if user input for  `speed_ms` is not integer
- If user presses any key before `t = input("GO!! ")` his reaction time is saved as 0. This is a major flaw in a code, and should be fixed.

Answer (score 12):

If it's wet, the `friction_coefficient` will be lower. Which means that `Bd` will be lower (which is probably wrong). 
It's difficult to see that, because of all the unnecessary parentheses. You missed the necessary ones.
You probably want

```
Bd = speed_ms**2 / (19.6 * friction_coefficient)
```

`Rt`, `Rd`, and `Bd` should get better names, or need a comment. In particular `Rt`, which probably means reaction time -- there already is a name `reaction_time` with a perfectly sensible value. That `Rt` contains a `sqrt` is suspicious. It needs a comment, *if* it is correct.

Comment: That square root looks completely wrong to me.  `reaction_time` is a perfectly sensible time in seconds, `Rt` is then used as a time in seconds - but it is a value with units "square-root-seconds".

Answer (score 12):

- `player_1` is read and assigned but never used.
- If the user misspells `wet` (e.g. as `Wet` or as `wet`), the program assumes that `dry` was meant - it should ask again until it gets an answer it understands or the player gives up (and consider adding `icy` for more fun).
- There's a lot of unnecessary parentheses - they could be trimmed to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Don't rely on users following your instruction to enter in lower case. Do `conditions = input("Wet or dry conditions? (all lowercase)").lower()`. Instead of doing `if else`, check each possibility separately, and ask again if it's neither (you might want to do `'wet' in conditions` rather than `'wet' == conditions in case they put an extra space at the end or something).

Since you're going to divide by a non-integer, you're going to end up with float anyway, so it's probably better to cast `speed` as a float to begin with, and avoid rounding if they don't enter an integer. You should also do a `try` block to catch people entering non-numbers.

Comment: If you're going to convert to lower-case anyway (which is a good thing to do), why prompt the user to type in lower-case?

Comment: @DavidRicherby 1. I didn't think it was worth changing. 2. Redundancy is good. 3. If a user is unsure what format to use, telling them to use lower case is simpler than saying "Hey, we case everything as lower case, so don't worry about what case".

Answer (score 2):

Output formatting: Your [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) calls output spaces between the comma-separated arguments; this causes output like:

```
Your final reaction time was:  1.6 !
```

Those extra spaces are ugly. An easy fix is the `sep` argument for `print`:

```python
print('Your final reaction time was: ', (Rt), '!\n', sep='')
```

```
Your final reaction time was: 1.6!
```

This will print no spaces between the three parts. Alternatively, you could do some string concatenating, but I prefer the first approach.

I would also drop the colon and include a unit for this measurement:

```
Your final reaction time was 1.6 seconds!
```

<sub>Slowest gun in the west...</sub>